# android ffmpeg create mp4 with bitmaps (no jpg)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android, video-codecs

on my android app, i have series of bitmaps generate by this method:

```
public Bitmap createFrame(int i) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(800, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    .
    .
    return bitmap;
}
```

now i want like this for ffmpeg command for convert all bitmaps to one mp4 video:

```
for (int i=0; i<500; i++) {
    Bitmap frame = frameBitmap(i);
    String cmd = "ffmpeg -y -i <<all frameBitmap">> ... libx264 ... output.mp4"
}
```

how to use one command with series of bitmaps?

Answer (score 2):

## Pipe as input

If your images can be piped out from whatever is generating them you can use the pipe protocol. Example to read from stdin:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Alternatively you could use `pipe:` or plain `-` to do the same thing.

See the [pipe protocol documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe) for more info.

## Saved images as input

If you have a series of image files, such as `img001.bmp`, `img002.bmp`, etc., you can use:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%03d.bmp -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Or you can use the *glob pattern* which supports a wildcard:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -pattern_type glob -i "*.bmp" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

See the [image file demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) for details.